# React-native missing index files

Tags: react-native

i am trying to start learning React-Native and I'm going over the guides in the offcial site.
but i am trying to understand why after running the command react-native init HelloWorld ,i am not getting the files for each os
i am using Mac os and according to the tutorials i should have 2 files for each OS,
index.android.js
index.ios.js

but i am not getting any one of those just main App.js file.

what am i missing?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React Native version 0.45 changed this, now it just uses a single entry file (*index.js*). See [issue #14246](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14246).